# Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, cell

```
for ch=1:63
    for h=1:5
        for a=1:6
            for b=1:6
                m{a,b}{h,ch}=zeros(4,4);
            end
        end
    end
end


for a=1:6
    for b=1:6
        if b==a
            for h=1:5
                for ch=1:63
                    for c=1:4
                        for d=1:4
                            m{a,b}{h,ch}{c,d}=1;
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The error was appeared in line 17 (  `m{a,b}{h,ch}{c,d}=1;` ),it showed that the cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object. Any solution to solve this type of error?

Comment: In line 17 and 18, replace the last curly brackets by normal parentheses: ` m{a,b}{h,ch}(c,d)=1;` and `p{a,b}{h,ch}(c,d)=1;`.

Comment: @H.Muster what do we know of `p`? are you sure it is also a 4x4 array and not a cell array?

Comment: @Shai Yes, you are right, I just replaced the brackets there without thinking about it. But nevertheless I would bet that `p` will just look like `m`.

Comment: sorry for type error,thanks for your help!!

Comment: @TonyYEe - please consider using `deal` and `cell` commands to construct `m`. Moreover, when you set `m{}{}() = 1` for `a==b` why do you loop over both `a` and `b`? wouldn't it be simpler to use one `for` loop: `for a=1:6, b = a; for h=1:5 ...` etc. ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a horrible code.

As for the error, the variable referenced to by `m{a,b}{h,ch}` was assigned in line 5 to a 4x4 **array** not a cellarray. Therefore, you should change line 17 to

```
m{a,b}{h,ch}(c,d)=1;
```

Note the difference between regular parentheses (when accessing arrays) and curly braces (when accessing cellarrays).