# Print all elements of a struct

Tags: matlab

I am just approaching Matlab, I have a function with a struct:

```
function [out] = struct1()

Account(1).name = 'John';
Account(1).number = 321;
Account(1).type = 'Current';

%.......2 to 9 

Account(10).name = 'Denis';
Account(10).number = 123;
Account(10).type = 'Something';

for ii= 1:10
out=fprintf('%s\n','%d\n','%s\n',Account{ii}.name, Account{ii}.number,Account{ii}.type);
end
end
```

The above code gives me an error: "Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object."

How do I output all elements of such struct to get this output using "fprintf"?

> name: 'John'
>
> number: 321
>
> type: 'Current'
>
> ```
>           ...... 2 to 9
> ```
>
> name: 'Denis'
>
> number: 123
>
> type: 'Something'

Comment: As a side note to the answer, the output a `fprintf` is simply the number of bytes written.  I'm not sure if you need this information but calling `fprintf` without an output is okay here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265311/cell-contents-assignment-to-a-non-cell-array-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indexing the elements of the struct array with `{` and `}` which are only used for cell arrays.  Simple `(` and `)` will work just fine.

Also, since you have the line breaks in the `formatspec`, you should just combine all three strings together.

Example:

```
formatspec = 'name: %s\nnumber: %d\ntype: %s\n';
for ii= 1:10
    out=fprintf(formatspec,Account(ii).name,Account(ii).number,Account(ii).type);
end
```

Comment: Please look at my output, I need the non numeric output between ''

Comment: @FeliceM Sorry, I don't understand the request.  The order of information in my code is the same as requested in the question.